Local behavior of Wronskian implies linear independence over an interval
Let $I$ be a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$, and let $x_1,x_2$ be real valued functions on $I$. If there is a point $x_0\in I$ such that $W(x_1,x_2)(x_0)\neq 0$, then $x_1, x_2$ are linearly independent over $I$.
I understand the proof of this statement. One can easily do it via contradiction and you will end up with $W$ being identically zero over $I$.
What I want is an interesting example illustrating this theorem. All the examples that I have tried to construct till now have the property that $W\neq 0$ for all $x\in I$. I want to see two functions whose Wronskian vanishes over $I$ frequently (whatever that might mean, it could be at finite points or almost everywhere) but $W$ turns out to be non zero for some points and not on the entire interval.

You probably need a differential equation that becomes degenerate for some value of $t$.

Take $x_1(t)=\sin(t)$, $x_2(t)=\sin(2t)$. Then $W(x_1,x_2)(t)=2\sin(t)\cos(2t)-\sin(2t)\cos(t)$ vanishes for $t=k\pi$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
